# Is Netty Channel.write thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, netty, channel

I have a Netty app, where I want to have more than one threads to be writing to a channel. I was just wondering whether Channel.write is thread safe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10702210/828625

Comment: I don't know, I might be wrong. But this http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/netty-users/2008-November/000045.html seems to conflict the remarks in the thread you quoted.

Comment: Again, what you have linked says the same thing, and answers your question. Channel.write is thread-safe.

Answer (score 7):

As you can see from the code, the `ChannelOutboundBuffer.addMessage()` method itself is not thread safe. However, Writing channel is "thread safe" because netty executes the write task/method in the single I/O thread.

Answer (score 3):

It's thread safe so you don't need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's thread-unsafe, because `Channel.write` calls `ChannelOutboundBuffer.addMessage` in its pipeline's HeadContext, and `ChannelOutboundBuffer.addMessage` is definitely thread-unsafe. Have a look at this code:

```
 public void addMessage(Object msg, int size, ChannelPromise promise) {
     Entry entry = Entry.newInstance(msg, size, total(msg), promise);
     if (tailEntry == null) {
         flushedEntry = null;
         tailEntry = entry;
     } else {
         Entry tail = tailEntry;
         tail.next = entry;
         tailEntry = entry;
     }
     if (unflushedEntry == null) {
         unflushedEntry = entry;
     }

     // increment pending bytes after adding message to the unflushed arrays.
     // See https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1619
     incrementPendingOutboundBytes(size, false);
 }
```

Comment: so you should have at most one thread calling Channel.write at any time.  there's something wrong with the format of the code, you can find it on http://netty.io/4.0/xref/index.html

Comment: I'm not able to confirm your claim. I see that `AbstractChannel.write` calls `Pipeline.write`, who eventually calls `AbstractUnsafe.write`, after it acquired the event loop for that channel. Inside this method there is an assert that the thread is inside the event loop, so it can only be called by 1 thread at a time