# Send message to client any moment Netty Io

Tags: java, server, netty

I have an architecture based on micro services, netty io runs on a spring boot application, when I want to send a message to a client I have to wait for a message from the client to send the reply to the one I want to send.
How could I send a message to the client without waiting for him to communicate with me?
I'm lost in this step.

Comment: Use two connections, or check how http pipelining is done (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining).

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: In netty, no clue, but with raw tcp, use one connection to send, one to receive.

Comment: You can save the message into a message queue(like rabbitmq),and then return back to server direct.On the other hand, you will retrieve the message from that message queue and send the reply to someone that you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can process like that :

1. Let the client connect on your server
2. Let the client send a Hello Message (to be sure is one of your client)
3. Catch the message on the server and store a reference on the channel (which is available on each channel handler by calling [`ctx.channel()`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html#channel--))
4. Catch [`channelInactive`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.html#channelInactive-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext-) event to remove the reference when the client disconnects

Instead of waiting for a HelloMessage, you can also catch the [`channelActive`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.html#channelActive-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext-) event but it is fired each time somebody connects to your listened port, even if is not one of your client. That's why I prefer using an "Hello Message"

Now, you have a reference on the channel and you can send a message when you want by calling [`channel.writeAndFlush()`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelOutboundInvoker.html#writeAndFlush-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: But one of my doubts would be, how could I use this channel that is open from another micro service? I could throw this in a variable and encapsulate it to consume from an async method?

Comment: Nope you can't, probably you need to define a different worflow, for example with a microservice which role is to receive/deliver message (like a Publish-Subscribe pattern), we've not much information about your achitecture and your code about that

Comment: The idea is for the endpoint to receive a command that should be sent to the client, to receive this command and through a queue in RabbitMQ send it to all the Socket server nodes and see what the client is and send the message through a consumer From the queue

Comment: But I saw that `channel.write()` or `channel.writeAndFlush()` is not thread-safe [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095044/is-netty-channel-write-thread-safe], so I end up with publishing all write-request to a ring-buffer to be handled by single-thread. Any idea about this? actively sending message to a client, or talk between clients is quite common scenario, need to be addressed.